# Excel macro to send Outlook emails will not send

Tags: excel, email, outlook

I have this code which uses an Excel sheet to create Outlook emails with attachments. It creates the emails correctly and `Display` works fine, but I cannot get `SendUsingAccount` to send the emails (manual sending of each email after `Display` works fine).

Could someone please point out the error?

Many thanks!

```
Sub Send_Files()

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim olApp As Object, olMail As Object, olRecip As Object, olAtmt As Object
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim Recip As String, Subject As String, Atmt As String
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
    Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
   
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   iRow = 2

   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mailinglist_1")

   Do Until IsEmpty(Sht.Cells(iRow, 1))

      Recip = Sht.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
      Subject = Sht.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
      Atmt = Sht.Cells(iRow, 3).Value 

      Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

      With olMail
            Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
            Set olMail.SendUsingAccount = OutAccount
            
            .Subject = "Test 2021"
            .Body = "Dear " & Sht.Cells(iRow, 1).Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Text" & vbNewLine & _
                "Text" & vbNewLine & _
                "The Team"

            olRecip.Resolve
            
            Set olAtmt = .Attachments.Add(Atmt)
            Set .SendUsingAccount = OutAccount

      .Send
      End With

      iRow = iRow + 1

   Loop

   Set olApp = Nothing

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try the following, Remove `.Display` and then put `.Send` just before `End With`

Comment:  Thanks @5202456 - problem solved!

Comment: Code above edited to implement @5202456's solution